# SQL Server : IF condition not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this condition in my stored procedure to determine which `WHERE` clause to use:

```
IF (@communityDesc = 'All Areas')
BEGIN
    WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC IN (SELECT name 
                                               FROM dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)) 
      AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE()
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE()
END
ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
```

but I get a long list of errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetProductionSchedule, Line 256
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetProductionSchedule, Line 256
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just put all of the logic into a single WHERE

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Table]
WHERE   V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE()
        AND (@communityDesc = 'All Areas'
             OR V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC IN (SELECT  name
                                                    FROM    dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)))
```

Im not sure you have your logic right..   You probably want to split @communityDesc if it's not equal to `All Areas` I've updated my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can't separate out a query by a conditional.  You'd have to do something like.

```
if(@communityDesc = 'All Areas')
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM Table  
    WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC IN 
    (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)) 
    AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
END
else
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table  
    WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
END
```

Your other option would be to conditionally build the query:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000)

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ' 

 if(@communityDesc = 'All Areas')
 BEGIN
     SET @Query = @Query + 
     'WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC IN (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)) AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE() '
 END
 ELSE

     SET @Query = @Query + 
    'WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE() '
 BEGIN
     SET @Query = @Query + 'ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END'
 END

exec sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write it like this

```
-- your preceding select statements followed by this line
SELECT * FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
WHERE 
(
 @communityDesc = 'All Areas' AND 
 V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC IN (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)) AND 
V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()
)
OR
( @communityDesc <> 'All Areas' AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()
)
ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
```

This can also be simplified as

```
-- your preceding select statements followed by this line
SELECT * FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
WHERE 
  V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE() 
 AND NOT
  (
 @communityDesc <> 'All Areas' OR
 V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC not IN (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)) 
)
ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
```

which can be further optimized like below

```
    -- your preceding select statements followed by this line
   SELECT * FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
   LEFT JOIN (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc) Temp
     ON Temp.name=V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC 
    WHERE 
      V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE() 
     AND NOT
      (
     @communityDesc <> 'All Areas' OR  Temp.Name is null
      ) 
    )
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
```